# I'm trying to pass data from my calcArea function to my calcCost function ,but I'm having trouble with it

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to get my calcCost function to work now. It doesn't carry over the area variable. Any ideas why it doesn't work? I got the calcArea function working,but can I use the area values for the calcCost area values? I started trying to put a pointer in there, but I'm not familiar with them a whole lot yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Define Constants
#define SALESTAX .07
#define TILEONE 0.78
#define TILETWO 1.59
#define TILETHREE 0.89
#define TILEONECASE 17.44
#define TILETWOCASE 10.89
#define TILETHREECASE 15.50
#define TILESIZE1 2.25
#define TILESIZE2 0.97222
#define TILESIZE3 1.77777
// Prototypes
void welcomeMessage(void);
char SelectChoice();
double getLength();
double getWidth();
double calcArea(double len, double wid);
double calcCost(double area);
void endMessage(void);
//integar return type, parameters are void,Richard's Flooring main function allows users to calculate room area and buy flooring.
int main (void)
{
//declare variables
double len, wid, area, tileNeeded,subTotal, taxTotal, total,cost;
double *dp;
char answer, myChoice;
dp = &area;


// Greets users and identifities program.
welcomeMessage ();
//Loop continues until user is done calculating area and buying flooring.

    printf("Choice | Dimesions | Price | Sq.FT.per case|\n 1     | 18 x 18   | $%.2lf |         17.44 |\n 2     |  7 x 20   | $%.2lf |         10.89 |\n 3     | 16 x 16   | $%.2lf |         15.50 |\n",TILEONE, TILETWO, TILETHREE);

    myChoice = SelectChoice();
    len = getLength();
    wid = getWidth();
    // calcArea function is a double return type, it calculates the Area entered in by the user, its parameters are double len and double wid
    area = calcArea(len,wid);
    printf("The area of your room is: %g square feet.\n",area);
calcCost(area);
//Provides users with publisher's name.
endMessage ();

return 0;
}
// no return type, tells users what kind of program they are using, and voids any parameters.
void welcomeMessage (void)
{
    printf("Welcome to Richard's Flooring\n");
    system ("pause");
    return ;
}

 // no return type, allows user to select choice
 char SelectChoice()
{
     char myChoice;

     do
     {
         printf("\nWhich tile choice would you like: ");
         scanf(" %c", &myChoice);

         switch(myChoice)
         { 
         case '1':
             printf("You chose choice: 1");
             break;


         case '2':
             printf("You chose choice: 2");
             break;


         case '3':
             printf("You chose choice: 3");
             break;


         default:
             printf("\nINVALID CHOICE 1 - 3 only!");

         }
     }

     while (myChoice > '3'|| myChoice < '1');
     return myChoice;

}

double getLength()
{
  double len;
 // loop continues until positive numbers are entered.
  do
  {
        printf("\nEnter length of room in feet: ");
        scanf(" %lf", &len);
        if (len <= 0)
        printf("\nLength must be positive number.");
  }
  while (len <=0);
  return len;
}


 double getWidth()
{
double wid;
// loop continues until positive numbers are entered.
do
{
    printf("\nEnter width of room in feet: ");
    scanf(" %lf", &wid);
    if (wid <= 0)
        printf("\nWidth must be positive number.");
}
while (wid <=0);
return wid;
}

// Double return type, which is returning Area. Calculates the Area in a  square or rectangle with the formula length * width. Accepts parameters from  double len and double wid.
double calcArea(double len, double wid)
{
    double area;
    area = (len * wid);
    return area;
}

double calcCost(double area)
{
    SALESTAX ;
    double  len, wid, tileNeeded,subTotal, taxTotal, total,cost;
    char answer, myChoice;
    area = calcArea(len,wid);

    do
    {


    char myChoice;
    if (myChoice == '1')
            {
                tileNeeded = area/TILESIZE1;
            }

    else if (myChoice == '2')
            {
                tileNeeded = area/TILESIZE2;
            }

    else if (myChoice == '3')
            {
                tileNeeded = area/TILESIZE3;
            }
    printf("You will need %.2lf pieces of tile\n", tileNeeded);
    subTotal = tileNeeded * TILETHREE;
    printf("Your subtotal is: $%.2lf \n", subTotal);
    taxTotal = subTotal * SALESTAX;
    printf("Your sales tax comes out to be: $%.2lf \n", taxTotal);
    total = taxTotal + subTotal;
    printf("Your grand total is: $%.2lf \n",total);
    printf("Would you like to measure another room?\n y or n:");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    }

 while (answer == 'y'|| answer == 'Y');
 }

// no return type, tells users Richard made the program, voids any parameters
void endMessage (void)
{
    printf("\nThese results were provided by Richard Triplett\n");
    system ("pause");
    return ;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is.  What do you mean by "it doesn't carry over the area variable"?  See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems that the area variable from the calcArea function isn't passing the value over to the calcCost function. When I compile the code it returns bad data in the statements in calcCost.

Comment: Well, that could just be the odd SALESTAX; kind of declaration(?)-looking thing you did.  Maybe remove that line? Since it justs says "0.7;" for no reason? Also, you realize you're passing in area, not len and wid, but you're USING len and wid in there... to overwrite the area you did pass in?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) separate functions: suggest by 2 blank lines 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a single blank line 3) consistently indent the code: suggest 4 spaces   indent after every opening brace '{'. un-indent before every closing brace '}' 4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: have you tried compiling the code?  When compiling, always enable all the warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` ) )   Then fix the problems expressed by the compiler messages.

Comment: in the function: `calcCost()` there is this line: `SALESTAX ;` where SALESTAX is #defined as `.07`.   That line does not compile.  (actually there are a lot of lines in the posted code that do no compile.)

Comment: do not use tabs for indenting.  Because each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  Always use spaces.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows for many indent levels across the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main you have these lines which calculate the area and pass it to calcCost:

```
area = calcArea(len,wid);
printf("The area of your room is: %g square feet.\n",area);
calcCost(area);
```

This should work correctly but in calcCost you have:

```
double  len, wid, tileNeeded,subTotal, taxTotal, total,cost;
char answer, myChoice;
area = calcArea(len,wid);
```

This recalculates the area on the basis of the len and wid variables defined in calcCost. Both of these are never set to a specific value and thus their values are indeterminate which leads to the overall area being indeterminate.

If you remove the `area = calcArea(len,wid);` line from calcCost then you will at least be using the correct value of area.

You will also have issues with myChoice as again this is redefined within calcCost and will have an indeterminate value. The simplest solution is probably to make myChoice an additional parameter to calcCost and pass it in from main.

The do loop in calcCost also doesn't work as required. It would return exactly the same answer every time 'y' or 'Y' was pressed. The do loop should probably be migrated into main but I have just removed it entirely for now.

Changes needed:

*in main*

```
calcCost(area,myChoice);
```

*in calcCost*

```
double calcCost(double area, char myChoice)
{
    double  tileNeeded,subTotal, taxTotal, total,cost;

    if (myChoice == '1')
            {
                tileNeeded = area/TILESIZE1;
            }

    else if (myChoice == '2')
            {
                tileNeeded = area/TILESIZE2;
            }

    else if (myChoice == '3')
            {
                tileNeeded = area/TILESIZE3;
            }
    printf("You will need %.2lf pieces of tile\n", tileNeeded);
    subTotal = tileNeeded * TILETHREE;
    printf("Your subtotal is: $%.2lf \n", subTotal);
    taxTotal = subTotal * SALESTAX;
    printf("Your sales tax comes out to be: $%.2lf \n", taxTotal);
    total = taxTotal + subTotal;
    printf("Your grand total is: $%.2lf \n",total);
 }
```